# Must a space homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ have a countable complement?

Tags: general-topology

There is a problem from a list suggested practice problems that I am having issues with. It says:

Suppose that $X$ is a subspace of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ which is homeomorphic to the space of irrational numbers. Is the complement of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily countable?

Would anyone be willing to help me out with this one? Thank you so much!

Comment: The complement is not necessarily countable (as easily seen by Asaf's hint), but it *is* necessarily dense (because $X$ is a zero-dimensional subspace of a connected space).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$.

Comment: Much simpler than the counterexample I was constructing to give an $X\subset(0,1)$ homeomorphic to the irrational numbers! I think I won't bother with mine, now.... XD

Comment: Great! What if we add the condition that $X$ is dense in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Cameron: Were you thinking about Cantor set minus endpoints?

Comment: @Hagen: That is an interesting question. My hunch is that the answer is no, I'll think of an argument and write another comment.

Comment: Precisely, Asaf.

Comment: @Hagen: every compact subset of $\mathbb{N^N}$ has empty interior, hence it's nowhere dense. Remove a Cantor set from the irrationals and the resulting space will still be dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @t.b.: It may be dense in $\mathbb R$, but I don't see immediately that it's still homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Hagen: Every Polish space which is $\sigma$-compact, and every compact subset has an empty interior is homeomorphic to the irrationals. It is not hard to verify that by removing a Cantor set from the irrationals these properties are unchanged.

Comment: @Hagen: An easier way to achieve the same: start with the usual Cantor set $C$ and take its complement $X = \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus C$. Write $X$ as a countable disjoint union of intervals and remove the rationals from each. Finish up by noting that a countable disjoint union of the space of irrationals is still homeomorphic to the space of irrationals.